# How to convert NCLOB data type to HTML

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have data base field that field data type is NCLOB. i get that data in to VARCHAR2 variable(or i can get that field value in to the NCLOB variable)

VARCHAR2 v1 :

```
&lt;img src=&quot;http://cdn.caradvice.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/mazda3-skyactiv-e1357269149782.jpg&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; style=&quot;border:0;min-height:auto;line-height:100%;outline:none;text-decoration:none&quot;&gt;
```

how i want to convert that v1 as bellow using p/l sql

VARCHAR2 v2 :

```
<img src="http://cdn.caradvice.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/mazda3-skyactiv-e1357269149782.jpg" border="0" alt="" style="border:0;min-height:auto;line-height:100%;outline:none;text-decoration:none">
```

please suggest p/l sql method for convert NCLOB value to string as HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT (your_string, 1) is what you need to use to unescape the special XMLcharacters.
More about this here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013100